# Always give one reputation point to user who post an answer

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers

I don't feel the following is fair.

If I answer a question but someone answered a few minutes before they get the reputation. If I help the asker he may thank me but neither accept my answer nor upvotes it, so I'm left with no reward for taking the time to try to help. I think this will lead people to lose interest in answering questions.

I think at least 1 point should be given if I provide an answer.

Comment: So, if you post 1000 really bad answers, you should get 1000 points of reputation?

Comment: Fact is, if you give a _good_ answer, in particular one that is better than the existing ones, you will get upvoted.

Comment: You have 14 SO answers with an average score just shy of 1. When just starting out this isn't bad. Keep answering and more importantly keep learning about both the subject and how to answer well and people will upvote you.

Comment: be patient, if your answer is good chances are eventually others will come across it days, weeks or months later and upvote it even if the OP doesn't acknowledge your answer

Comment: Thank you Ben. I'm not sending crap answers, and I'm not here only for reputation, I don't feel in community when I do my best to help the asker and I'm left without any type of reward, I understand the reputation as a "thank you". But also would be bad if people keep sanding crapy answers just for rep, I agree with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are in it for the rep, you will burn out pretty quickly. The fact is, while the shiny badges and reputation make answering questions exciting, most people are here because they

1. enjoy the sense of community
2. like being able to disseminate their expertise
3. benefit from the expertise of others

If you've posted a good answer, you get the satisfaction of knowing you've posted a good answer and will probably get some rep for it. No one is *obligated* to upvote your answers.

What you *can* do is:

- Throw in a few answers on mainstream, straightforward questions. If you focus exclusively on obscure, niche topics that not many people will see, you are unlikely to get votes
- Format your answers nicely
- Don't whine.

I disagree with your feature request because it would completely devalue reputation. Churning out a hundred throwaway answers a day is easy; writing four or five that people actually find helpful is what its about.

Comment: 4. hopelessly addicted to the rep and badges but are in denial.

Comment: I'm not burnt out yet. But I am also not very good at getting rep...

Answer (score 12):

We're not looking for quantity, we're looking for quality.  We want the best answers to get the most points, so that good answers are incentivized.  You will occasionally get hit-and-run questioners that don't upvote and accept properly, but by and large good answers will be rewarded.

Of course, in niche tags you see less voting in general, so the tag you're in matters a lot, which is why they created the badges like `Unsung Hero` and `Tenacious`.  The counterpoint to that is that in popular tags it's harder to be the first with a good answer.

Comment: **"not looking for quantity, we're looking for quality"** -- [1000 times yes](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/trial-run-of-modified-hotness-formula-for-programmers-questions#comment16048_5482 "about 10 bounties invested into related questions"). I'd rather _deduct_ 1 rep from one who posts the answer, to enforce this :)